# replace matching special characters pattern from a string

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
string s = "apple]","[banana...." ;
```

I need to remove ( "]","[ ) and replace with "," from above string so that the output looks like below:

```
s = "apple,banana...."
```

```
s = s.Replace(@"\]","[\", ",");  //something like this?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the quotation marks in the string. You have tried to escape something, but `\` isn't used to escape characters in a @ delimited string.

In a @ delimited string you use `""` to escape `"`:

```
s = s.Replace(@"]"",""[", ",");
```

In a regular string you use `\"` to escape `"`:

```
s = s.Replace("]\",\"[", ",");
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume it is a string[]?

I propose something like this:

```
    string[] s = {"[apple]","[banana]","[orange]"} ;
    string new_s = "";
    foreach (string ss in s)
    {                
        new_s += ss.Replace("[", "").Replace("]", ",");                
    }

    //handle extra "," at end of string
    new_s = new_s.Remove(new_s.Length-1);
```

Edit: Disregard, I misunderstood what you were trying to accomplish due to syntactical errors in your string definition.

```
string s = "apple]","[banana...." ;
```

should be:

```
string s = "apple]\",\"[banana....";
```